# String index out of range on space bar character

Tags: java, string, substring, lastindexof, string-function

For example the name Donald trump (12 character) brings up the error string index out of range 7 (where the space is found) even though the name Donald trump is longer.

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Usernamesubstring {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fullname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your full name");
        int breakbetween = fullname.lastIndexOf(" ");
        String firstnamess = fullname.substring(breakbetween - 3, breakbetween);
        int length = fullname.length();
        String lastnamess = fullname.substring(length - 3, length);
        String firstnamec = firstnamess.substring(0, 0);
        String lastnamec = lastnamess.substring(breakbetween + 1, breakbetween + 1 );
        firstnamec = firstnamec.toUpperCase();
        lastnamec = lastnamec.toUpperCase();
        String firstname = firstnamess.substring(1,3);
        String lastname = firstnamess.substring(1,3);
        firstname = firstnamec + firstname;
        lastname = lastnamec + lastname;
        System.out.println(firstname + lastname);
}
}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
at test.Usernamesubstring.main(Usernamesubstring.java:14)

Comment: Which like throws the exception?

Comment: can you explain what you mean but i think the error comes from .lastIndexOf line 2

Comment: Btw. please come up with some reasonable variable names. I see no difference between `firstnamess`, `firstnamec` and `firstname` - it makes it impossible to understand what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: When you get an error it tells you in which line of code it happend. Just read the whole error. Or at least copy/paste it in the question.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
 at test.Usernamesubstring.main(Usernamesubstring.java:14)

Comment: Your String `lastnamess` is equal to `"ump"` with length = 3  and  you execute `lastnamess.substring(breakbetween + 1, breakbetween + 1)` with `breakbetween` that is equal to `6`, here the exception.

Comment: firstnamess is a substring to get the last three letters of your first name Donald - > ald firstnamec should make ald - > Ald and firstname is the final output

Comment: But that is going to bring " U" then it is added to "mp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: The exception occurs when you try to access a String at an index which exceeds it's length or is just not contained in the string (negative values).

Regarding your approach: It's usually not a good idea to prompt a name in full because people tend to input weird stuff or mix up the order. Better prompt for first and last name separately.

Assuming someone input his name with `Firstname Lastname` you wouldn't have to make such a substring mess, Java has some nice features:

```
    String name = "Mario Peach Bowser";
    name = name.trim();
    String[] parts = name.split(" ");
    String lastname = parts[parts.length-1];
    String firstname = name.replace(lastname, "").trim();
    System.out.println("Hello "+firstname+", your last name is: "+lastname);
```

In this case I am using the `trim()` function to remove whitespaces at the start and end and just split the string when a white space occurs. Since people can have some middle names and stuff, I just replace the last name out of the raw input string, call `trim()` on it again and you have everything extracted.

If you really want a substring approach, the following would work:

```
    String lastname = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(" ")).trim();
    String firstname = name.substring(0,name.lastIndexOf(" ")).trim();
```

You usually don't store the index variables. But each variant would need some sort of error check, you can either use `try{}` and `catch()` or check the `String` before parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You've made it more complicated than it needs to be. A simple solution can be made using [`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) (which divides a string into an array of smaller strings based on a delimiter, e.g. `"Donald Trump".split(" ") == {"Donald", "Trump"}`) 
Full Code

```java
class Usernamesubstring // change that since it no longer uses substrings
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String fullName = "Donald Trump";
        String[] parts = fullName.split(" ");
        String firstName = parts[0];               // first item before the space
        String lastName = parts[parts.length - 1]; // last item in the array
        
        System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

sometimes independent of your indexes

```
String fullName = "Donald Trump";
String[] result = fullName.split (" ");
```

in result you will find now
result [0] ==> Donald
result [1] ==> Trump

isn't that a little easier for your project?

Answer (score 1):

Your error shoul be in the line  `String lastnamec = lastnamess.substring(breakbetween + 1, breakbetween + 1 );` as lastnamess is a string of lenght 3 from `fullname.substring(length - 3, length);` and breakbetween is greater then 3 for "Donald Trump", where space is character 6.

You should simpify your code a bit, it makes it easier to read and find the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Only these lines are required.

```
String[] nameArr = fullname.split(" ");
String lastN = nameArr[nameArr.length - 1];
int lastIndexOf = fullname.lastIndexOf(lastN);
String firstN = fullname.substring(0, lastIndexOf);
System.out.println(firstN + " " + lastN);
```